# Ignore a label over clickable areas for mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this simplistic [JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/62rqP/), you can see a `div` with text over a `img`. The cursor can take one of three behaviors depending on where it hovers: **pointer** over `img`, **text selection** over `div`'s content and **default** when `outside` both:

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png">
<div>Stack Overflow</div>
```

```
img {position: absolute; clip: rect(0px, 238px, 61px, 0px); cursor: pointer;}
div {position: absolute; margin: 50px; border: 3px solid gray;}
```

How can you completely ignore `div`'s interference on cursor?

And by that I mean when you hover the cursor over `div` and `img` intersection you get only `img`'s behavior, and when over `div` and `outside` intersection you get only `outside`'s behavior.

- If you can, please avoid invisible layers or sending the `div` behind the `img`.
- If the solution involves **JavaScript** or **jQuery**, please do it!

*The solution would be useful for labeling on maps.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set the CSS property `pointer-events` to `none` on the div in question. You can find the pointer events specification [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)--the support isn't great (IE9+, mainly) but sounds like exactly what you need.